# Django template tag modifies the context of only one block

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I made a template tag with the objective of simplifying the inclusion of Angular.

The tag responsible for setting some variables in the context is the following:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def ng_controller(context, controller_name, file_name):
    context['angular_import'] = True
    context['angular_controller_file'] = file_name
    return 'ng-controller="{}"'.format(controller_name)
```

the root template has this block in place of the javascript imports

```
{% block container_content %}{% endblock %}
{% block angular_inclusion %}{% endblock %}
```

the template that inherits the root template is this

```
{% extends 'root.html' %}
{% block container_content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="well" {% ng_controller 'CreateEdictController' 'js/controllers/create-edict-controller.js' %}>
            {{ angular_controller_file }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block angular_inclusion %}
{{ angular_controller_file }}
{% endblock %}
```

I can successfully access `{{ angular_controller_file }}` in the first block, but not in the second block. How can I ensure the context manipulation affects the second block also?

Comment: I would have expected it to be the other way round, since you don't have `container_content` in the root...How are you verifying that you can/can't access the variable?

Comment: @Sayse sorry I omitted that. The root template does have the block `container_content`

Comment: It would appear as though the scope of the context variable is restricted to the same scope as the template tag, it might make more sense to use `include` to include a javascript file or html snippet, but I'm not sure I fully understand the use case

Answer (score 0):

> Variable scope in context
>
> Any variable set in the context will only be available in the same
>   block of the template in which it was assigned. This behavior is
>   intentional; it provides a scope for variables so that they don’t
>   conflict with context in other blocks.

So the tag call in the first block `container_content`:

```
<div class="well" {% ng_controller 'CreateEdictController' 'js/controllers/create-edict-controller.js' %}>
```

Is ignored and missing in the second block, `angular_inclusion`